# ¿Cómo puedo imprimir la primera columna de un archivo?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Necesito acceder sólo a la primera columna de un archivo:

```
luz NC  luz
mas ADV más
blanquita   ADJ blanco
que CQUE    que
las ART el
que CQUE    que
traía   VLfin   traer
de  PREP    de
serie   NC  serie
mi  PPO mi|mío
coche   NC  coche
```

Mi código:

```
with open ("corpus_TreeTagger.txt", "r") as f:
    texte = f.read()
    corpus = texte.split("\t")
    #print(texte)

    for linhas in corpus:
        print(linhas[0])
```

Produce este resultado:

```
l
N
l
A
m
A
b
C
q
A
e
C
q
V
t
P
d
N
s
P
m
N
c
```

Mientras que el resultado esperado es este:

```
luz 
mas 
blanquita 
que
las
que
traía
de 
serie
mi  
coche
```

Pero mi resultado no es correcto. ¿Alguien me puede ayudar? ¡Gracias!

Comment: Al estar separando por `\t` coge los espacios y tabs. Creo que deberias hacer split por salto de linea y despues a cada item en el array, aplicar un split por espacio y quedarte con el primer elemento.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prueba con esto:

```
with open ("corpus_TreeTagger.txt", "r") as f:
    texte = f.read()
    #separamos por línea. En curpus, por tanto tenemos una lista con todas las lineas
    corpus = texte.split("\n") 
    #print(texte)

    for linhas in corpus:
        #separamos por tabulador y cogemos el primero. 
        #[0] -> primera columna. 
        #[1] segunda columna...
        print(linhas.split('\t')[0])
```

Comment: Toma, hice una version online: https://www.ideone.com/waiuBS

Answer (score 1):

Ya sé que estás tratando de hacerlo con Python. Sin embargo, este es un caso prototípico en el que utilidades de la shell como AWK y sed lo solucionan de una forma más rápida y fácil.

Con AWK:

```
awk '{print $1}' fichero
```

Esto imprime el primer campo, teniendo en cuenta que estos están separados por espacios o tabuladores. Lo bueno de este método es que nos permite imprimir cualquier columna muy fácilmente, utilizando `$n`, con `n` el número de esta. Y como añadido interesante, podemos decir `awk '{print $NF}' fichero` para imprimir el último.

Con sed:

```
sed 's/\s.*//' fichero
```

Esto elimina todo a partir del primer carácter de espacio (espacio o tabulador).

Ambos casos devuelven lo siguiente:

```
luz
mas
blanquita
que
las
que
traía
de
serie
mi
coche
```

Answer (score 1):

Al reproducir ejemplos detecto que al recorrer el split del corpus, no puedes acceder al contenido de manera apropiada porque no se ha filtrado ciertos caracteres:

```
text = """luz NC  luz
mas ADV más
blanquita   ADJ blanco
que CQUE    que
las ART el
que CQUE    que
traía   VLfin   traer
de  PREP    de
serie   NC  serie
mi  PPO mi|mío
coche   NC  coche"""

corpus = text.split("\n") 
    #print(texte)
for linhas in corpus:
        #separamos por tabulador y cogemos el primero. 
        #[0] -> primera columna. 
        #[1] segunda columna...
        print([i for i in linhas.split(' ') if i!=''][0])
```

Salida para primera columna [0] , probar con un rango de 0 a n columnas.

```
Out[1]:
luz
mas
blanquita
que
las
que
traía
de
serie
mi
coche
```

Por lo que quedaría en forma de funcion a la que puedes incorporal la apertura de fichero si quieres:

```
def lee_col(text, pag):
    corpus = text.split("\n")
    out=[]
    for linhas in corpus:
        out.append([i for i in linhas.split(' ') if i!=''][pag])
    return out

lee_col(text,0)
```